# Organize modules according to inheritance and composition: Best practices

Tags: perl, organization

I have a set of modules I need to organize. It looks somewhat like a set of:

```
A.pm                    # Inherits from A_base
A_collection.pm         # Collection of a large number of instances of A
A_base.pm
```

The current structure I have is as follows:

```
.
|-- bin
|   `-- Main.pl
|-- lib
|   |-- A_base
|   |   `-- A.pm
|   `-- A_base.pm
`-- t
```

In this way, when I refer to **A.pm**, it becomes `...::A_base::A`, indicating that A_base is the parent.
What is the logical place to put in `A_collection.pm` into this structure? Is this structure right?

Answer (score 5):

Well, `A_base::A` only indicates inheritence from `A_base` if that's the convention you're using. There's no perl-based requirement for any such.

You might prefer something like:

```
A             - User typically uses these, inherits A::Base
A::Base       - base-class for A
A::Collection - lots of A's
A::Alt        - Alternative to "A", inherits A::Base
A::Plugin::X  - A plugin that does X
```

The main convention AFAIK with perl modules is that the top-level name should be a "topic". You might like to browse, e.g. the [Log::Dispatch](https://metacpan.org/search?q=log::dispatch) hierarchy, or perhaps Moo's extensions under [MooX](https://metacpan.org/search?q=moox), perhaps [MooX::Types](https://metacpan.org/search?q=moox::types). None of these follow a parent/child hierarchy in their naming.